# I got this weird message about forcing UEFI installation when trying to install ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, bios

I am trying to install ubuntu alongside windows 7 using a usb flash drive and when I went to install it I got this message:

"This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may be existing operating systems already installed using "BIOS compatibility mode". If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating systems later.
If you wish to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the ability to boot one of the existing systems, you have the option to force that here. If you wish to keep the option to boot an existing operating system, you should choose NOT to force UEFI installation here."

Then I have to options, 1. Go Back and 2. Continue in UEFI mode

I clicked go back and it still proceeded to the next part of the installation, so I quit so I can ask here if I am doing something wrong because I don't want to mess with anything in windows 7 or my BIOS after I install ubuntu. I have used this flash drive to install ubuntu alongside windows 7 on two other pcs and never got that message.

What does this message mean? Should I be doing something differently?
I don't even know what Debian is (I am trying to install Ubuntu)?

Comment: You never got the message before because the others were not UEFI. You need to install in the same mode the already installed OS was and how it boots is how it installs. Knowing that it's easy to understand you booted the installer in UEFI mode which is fine **if** the other OS is in the same mode.

Comment: @MichaelBay according to the message it looks like I had installed windows 7 on my computer using "bios compatibility mode", how can I check that to make sure, if it's true is it possible to install ubuntu alongside windows 7 in "bios compatibility mode"?

Comment: Yes, it's possible either way. Check your disk (you can use Disks or GParted in the live session), if there's a small EFI partition that means UEFI mode, legacy otherwise. When both modes are enabled in the UEFI settings you'll notice that there are two entries for the USB stick, one mentioning UEFI. Use the other in order to boot in legacy mode and install as usual.

Comment: Windows 7 DVD is BIOS only install. You have to copy to flash drive and move/rename a few files to make it UEFI bootable for UEFI install. But if you have new UEFI hardware, you may want to reinstall Windows in UEFI mode to take full advantage of new system.